# How to pass a instance of a google api connected client

Tags: android-intent, android-fragments, bundle, google-fit

I am suffering from a bit of confusion around the google fit and google + api. When my app is first opened the user is asked to sign in with google + etc and then, if they are logged in, are transfered via intent to my home class. This class sets up some fragments for the user profile area.

The bit I am confused about is how to recall this client from a fragment later on? As far as I am aware you cannot transfer the client instace in a bundle? Is it a case that I would have to run my who login bit again to retrieve the client, obviously as they have already approved my app it should just happen automatically or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using a Subclass application, thanks to this post : [Pass connection object to other activity - Google Tasks API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20198114/pass-connection-object-to-other-activity-google-tasks-api?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

If i understood the question correctly, I would make a "public static" object of googleAPIClient variable, you should be able to login in one activity and then use same instance in any other activity/fragment/etc as well...